# relacing $_FILES name and temp name by using a file url

Tags: php, forms

Hi am using a form to upload a pdf file to extarct its sample pages
:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="inputfile" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Extract Pages" />
</form>
```

And the process is accesiing the pdf file details using which rest of the functionality depends
The process.php contains:

```
$FileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['name'];
$TempFileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'];
$Folderpath='/home/domain/public_html/pdftest/temp';
```

here am getting filename  and temp filename using the file uplaod process,but i want to get those information using the file url like www.domainname.com/docs/1.pdf and without a form uploading process

how to change it?

Comment: as the 2 answers below show, what you actully want is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You must be knowing, currently the uploaded file resided in the 'tmp' folder, with '$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name']' being the file name.

For the file to be accessible via a url you have to move the file to required folder, say your destination folder is `upload`,then you should add something like this to your code

```
     $target_path = "uploads/";
     $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."has been uploaded";        
     } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on your server and you have the URL, you can get the path to the file like this:

```
$url = 'www.domainname.com/docs/1.pdf'; // Or get `$url` some other way
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$url_parts['path'];
```

Then `$filepath` is the full path to the PDF file.

Note: There is no file name or temp file name when you are not uploading a file.

You can probably fake the file name and temp file name with the following:

```
$TempFileName = $filepath;
$FileName = basename($filepath);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply,i just need filename and file temp name of a file based on file url,i need that two varibles values for my further process

Comment: Is the "file url" a location on your own server or is it a URL on another website?

Comment: the pdf files are in my own server

Comment: @user4022479 Updated my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: here is the code plz check,
 $FileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['name'];$TempFileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'];   try {
GetExtract($TempFileName,$FileName); 
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  $responce = DecryptPDF($Folderpath,$FileName,$TempFileName);   if($responce == ''){
   $Inputfile = $Folderpath.'/un_'.$FileName;
   GetExtract($Inputfile,$FileName);
  }else{
   echo $responce;   
  }
 }

Comment: in above comment u will find the code and the process and i am new to php,can u plz tell me how to send filename and tempfile name in that functions by using file url

Comment: I don't know what `GetExtract` or `DecryptPDF` do. Like I said in my answer, there is no file name or temp file name if you aren't doing a file upload. I gave you a way to find the system path to a file on your server given the URL. You are going to have to figure out what to do from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply,getextarct funtions will extract the pages from uploaded file,if any error in extraction we will decrypt the file and again we will send the file to getextrcat function and am trying to do the whole process without upload like this  $FileName = "10.pdf";
        
 $TempFileName = "tempname.pdf" apology if am not clear

Comment: It sounds like `GetExtract()` and `DecryptPDF()` are written to specifically handle a file that has been uploaded. If you want to things to work without doing a file upload, you are going to have to change how those functions work.

Comment: yes,yes its written for uploaded file, but i want to solve the issue in the initial stage only,can we do this by get file contents or put file contents?please guide me how to solve it

Comment: Ok. I really cannot help you further. You're going to have to figure out how those functions work and set things up appropriately.